# Capybara click_button works, but how do I evaluate the JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, cucumber, capybara

Soo, if Capybara can interface with the DOM and my app makes a form submit via AJAX and returns some JSON, can Capybara see that at all?  I'm not finding any way to get to the AJAX response in the Capybara API.

Here's an example of kinda what I'm doing:

```
# Cucumber step_definition
Then(/^I should be able to create a household$/) do
  click_link 'Next'
  page.should have_selector 'form#household-form'
  fill_in 'Name', with: name = Faker::Name.last_name
  click_button 'Create'
  page.wait_until do
    page.evaluate_script('$.active') == 0 # really awesome hack to wait for ajax
  end
  @user.reload.households.first.name.should eq name
end
```

I'd rather not hit the database again to test the result, but instead do something like:

```
xhr.response_data.should be_json
```

Verifying that my json response is what I thought it should be.

I'm just experimenting here, trying to get used to Cucumber and Capybara.

Comment: So I take it this is impossible?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find any information to this meanwhile?

Answer (score 3):

You should mark your scenario / feature to run as a JavaScript feature by tagging it with `@javascript`:

```
@javascript
Scenario: Title goes here
```

What this will do is to tell Cucumber to run the selenium-webdriver gem which will launch a real browser (Firefox) and run the test inside that browser. The browser will of course evaluate the JavaScript and then Capybara will be able to see what it outputs.

Comment: Yeah, I already have `@javascript` above the scenario definition, it all works great, except I would like to know how I can get at the JSON response after it occurs (and maybe keep track of dom events in the process).  The AJAX response does not affect anything on the page, so I can't use `page` to evaluate what happened.